# Complicated 301 redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need a bit of help with .htacces file.

I jave tried the solution proposed here: [Redirecting old .html page to new without html extension page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926237/redirecting-old-html-page-to-new-without-html-extension-page), but, for me, it does not work.

To redirect from uppercase to lowercase, for me, this code works just fine: [Redirecting uppercase urls to lowercase urls using htaccess.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49261847/redirecting-uppercase-urls-to-lowercase-urls-using-htaccess)

However, I am still unable to redirect 301 the following:

```
/postname.html to /category/category/category/category/postname.html
/postname.html to /category/category/category/postname.html

/PostName.html (### please notice the caps ###) to /category/category/category/category/postname.html
/PostName.html (### please notice the caps ###) to /category/category/category/postname.html

/PoștName.html (### please notice the special caracter "ș" and the uppercase ###) to /category/category/category/category/postname.html
/PoștName.html (###  please notice the special caracter "ș" and the uppercase ###) to /category/category/category/postname.html

/category/postname.html to /category/category/category/category/postname.html
/category/postname.html to /category/category/category/postname.html

/category/PostName.html (### please notice the uppercase ###) to /category/category/category/category/postname.html
/category/PostName.html (### please notice the uppercase ###) to /category/category/category/postname.html

/category/PoștName.html (### please notice the special caracter "ș" and the uppercase ###) to /category/category/category/category/postname.html
/category/PoștName.html (###  please notice the special caracter "ș" and the uppercase ##) to /category/category/category/postname.html
```

Any help, please ?!

Comment: Nobody ? I really need some help, please.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to show us what you actually tried, not just tell us _“am still unable to”_ …